# Apache ServerName uses AlternativeName instead of CommonName

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, mod-ssl

I have recently purchased an SSL Certificate. The CommonName (CN) of the certificate is `www.mydomain.com` and has several AlternativeNames such as `subdomain1.mydomain.com`, `subdomain2.mydomain.com` etc.

I have installed this on a server using Apache 2.2.17 and mod_ssl, and all works fine, except I am gettings a warning saying:

```
[warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `www.mydomain.com` does NOT match server name!?
```

This is because the `ServerName` is defined as `subdomain1.mydomain.com`. The certificate is still valid, but is there anything I can do to remove the warning? Or can I just ignore it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignore it.

It's doing some very basic validity checks, that would hold true if you weren't using alternate names - a client browser's validity checking is much more robust, and as you know, has no problem with the certificate.

If you have more than one `VirtualHost` on an SSL port, you'll probably see a warning for that, too.  Same deal - it's designed to warn you if something's not making sense for a simple, basic config - but you know that it's working like it's supposed to, so you can disregard.